# Can i nest the disabled attribute using LESS?

Tags: html, css, less

I have the following code to target buttons that are in a disable state:

```
.btn-default[disabled] {
  background-color: lighten(@btn-default-bg, 30%)
}
```

Is it possible to use nested rules to target the disabled attribute? something similar to &:Hover

Comment: I think you can... Does `&:disabled` work?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can indeed, like this:

```
.btn-default {
  &[disabled] {
    background-color: lighten(@btn-default-bg, 30%)
  }
}
```

http://jsbin.com/aKuLire/1/edit

You can even do further nesting:

```
input {
  &[type="submit"] {
    &[disabled] {
      background: @blue;
    }
  }
}
```